# Should I create a new git repository or a new git branch for my new version of application?

Tags: git, version-control, aws-lambda

I have a node.js application (version 1.0) which runs on AWS EC2.

Now I'm going to move all the functions of it to AWS lambda (Let's call this version 2.0), making it a serverless application.

Because the content of the code of version 2.0 is quite different from that of version 1.0, I'm wondering if I should create a new git repository for version 2.0 or create a new git branch for version 2.0.

If I create a new git repository, there will be 2 repositories which provide exactly the same service. I don't think this should happen.

If I create a new git branch, how can I merge this new branch back to master branch? Just replace the content of master branch with `version 2.0` branch?

This application is not written just by me, but also by other coworkers in my company. What is the best decision in this situation?

Comment: If you expect to bring content from this new version back into the old version, then creating a new branch probably makes the most sense.  Look into git merge for more information.

Comment: **Create a new branch** for developing the code version 2.0, or **add a tag** to record code version 1.0 and then continue develop code version 2.0 on the same branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a branch. That let you the time to decide, by experience, if that suits you.

You will anyway be able to create the repository from the branch in the future if you decide it worth it...

You should create a new repository, if you are sure that the 2 projects are not linked at all. If you have doubts, you should take the branch strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain in future your new bracnh and do only bugfixes in the old one, make a bracnh for the "released" current version 1.0 and use master branch for your new version 2.0.

Creating a new repo would put additional difficulties on merging fixes of one branch to the other on your shoulders.